# Android: Background Service won't stop

Tags: android, service, background

Greetings,

I have the following service running in the background:

https://gist.github.com/807968

When I close the application, the user is asked if they'd like to continue to upload their GPS coordinates in the background. When 'Yes' is clicked, the service works just fine. When 'No' is clicked, the app shuts down as expected, but it still uploads the GPS coordinates in the background! I can even see the little GPS icon in the status bar of my Android phone. I expect to see a "Stopped" Toast, but it never appears...

Anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using START_STICKY so the service won't stop unless explicitly told to. In the code handling the response for "No" you need to call stopService(). Here is a link to documentation on [service life cycles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)